# Cannot log in via chroot SSH

Tags: ssh, user-management, chroot

I not only want to transmit files via sftp, but also want to log in via ssh.

Here is what I changed in sshd_config

```
Match Group ssh_jail
    ChrootDirectory /mnt/chroot
```

I have mounted /mnt/chroot/dev, /mnt/chroot/dev/pts, /mnt/chroot/proc, /mnt/chroot/sys
I have also copied bash to /mnt/chroot/bin and some lib files to /mnt/chroot/lib64

But I cannot log in via ssh. Below is what I found in /var/log/secure

```
Accepted password for xxx from ::1 port 53069 ssh2
pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user xxx by (uid=0)
error: mm_receive_fd: no message header
fatal: mm_pty_allocate: receive fds failed
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user xxxx
```

Why is that?

Comment: You copied "some" lib files.  Did you copy enough lib files?  Have you tried `chroot /mnt/chroot /bin/bash -i` to see if bash works in your chroot?

Comment: @DerfK bash works. Lib files are enough I think.

Comment: Not necessarily. What did you use to tell you the library files to copy? Did you run `ldd` on the `sshd` binary and verify that all of those are present? The failure to allocate a pty (pseudo-terminal) is rather suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I disabled SELinux and rebooted, then everything works fine now.